# Android check sms

Tags: android, sms

How can I check if the device has SMS capabilities (e.g phones probably will but tablets might not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the question myself, I'm using;

```
if(this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)){
  // THIS PHONE HAS SMS FUNCTIONALITY
}else{
  // NO SMS HERE :(
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) being there or not. I guess unconnected tablets wont have it.

Comment: I am going the route of checking if PackageManager pm.hasSystemFeature(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) == false, because I believe you need TELEPHONY_SERVICE for SMS.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work. On my phone it returns fasle :) ...Time to think up a new idea :p

Comment: have u added permissions to ur project ??

Comment: What permission is needed for this? I didn't see one on the dev site?

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SEND_SMS